# Get extract value from fact

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

Im pretty new to prolog, and got stuck.
I need to store a variable with some string during calculations, I decided to do this by adding a "single fact" to the class I'm working with. Everything works well, the string is being stored, but when I try to add the code to access it later on, compiler returns an error `"The expression has type 'dataBL::dataBL@objectDB', which is incompatible with the type '::symbol'".`
I dont think it is the valid way to store a variable, so, can anyone help me with that? I tried searching online for the answers, and found nothing.

I'm trying to access the fact like this:

```
    getString(U) :-
    U = stringStorage(_).
```

Comment: Well, I googled a little bit more, checked tutorials that come with the system, and looks like this solution works: `getString(U) :-      stringStorage(U).`

But I'd really like some explanation on how it actually works...

Comment: Forget what you know about how other languages work. Prolog is different. It has *predicates*, not *functions*. *predicates* do not return values. The can accept arguments, but only either succeed, fail, or do not terminate (which is a problem if that happens). It attempts to instantiate any variables you give it that will lead to a successful query. So when you say `getString(U) :- stringStorage(U).` Prolog will look at facts and predicates called `stringStorage(Something)` and when it finds them, it looks for a value for your `U` which will cause it to succeed.

Comment: The `=/2` in Prolog is not an assignment operator. It's a *unification* operator. It attempts to *unify* its arguments. So when you say, `U = stringStorage(_)` it looks at the variables, in this case, `U` and `_` (an anonymous variable) and looks for ways to make this unification succeed. It actually does succeed by binding the term `stringStorage(_)` to `U`. So the result of the `getString(U)` query will be something like `U = stringStorage(_)`, just like you asked for. :)

Comment: Looks like you need find a good book or tutorial on Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you need to store a `value` associated with some variable ID (`key`) as a fact. The (abstract) solution for your task canas the storing your values as a facts:

`bind( Key, Value ).`

Example of implementation (SWI Prolog)

*Storing*

```
recordz('var1', "String value1"),

recordz('var2', "String value2")
```

*Querying* value of var2

```
current_key(-Key), 

Key = 'var2'

recorded(Key, Value)
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I felt like an idiot when I reread my question. Forgot about binding and the fact that prolog is different.